# Collect information of members of a Class using Reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I'm trying to collect information about members of a class in Java using the standard reflection API. I've been successful for the most part except for members which are java collections and nested. Something like...

```
class Foo {
    int bar;
    List<List<List<String>>> baz; // problematic.
}
```

I'm collecting all this information into a Map via recursing over nested fields.

```
Recurse(Foo) -> Recurse(baz) -> Recurse(List<List<String>>) -> Recurse(List<String>)...
```

If there is already a library to help with some of this which I might have skipped, please mention it. Much appreciated :)

Comment: If your question is "How can I know the generic type of the List by reflection", you cannot. It will probably be possible from Java 9 thanks to the reifed generics.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the generic type for a *field* via reflection with `Field.getGenericType()`,

You can't for the `List` that `baz` refers to.

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for the answer. I'm new to Java (static typed languages in general). If I can't use reflections to get that information, any ideas how I can go about this?

Comment: @saket There is no simple way to find this out.  Why are you trying to do this as there might be another way to achieve that?